# Liferay jboss : Handle 500 exception

Tags: jboss, liferay-6

```js
JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000145: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

JBWEB000070: exception

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host/empAppMgmt-portlet/aggregate/https_/empAppMgmt-portlet/js/empAppMgmt.jsbrowserId=firefox&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6210&t=1424361709000&fakeParam=%24{76428%2b66104%2b%27f60cec015d33e6f70fc90789dd6659ff6b83da4d49f58d1fb7d1f0ae210ff7a8de500d534018c03aa77a440178e47b9e9dc66b53afa119163810502c2d1946f2%27}_E_CONTENT_TYPE (File name too long)
 java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
 com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:949)
 com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:927)
 com.liferay.portal.util.FileImpl.write(FileImpl.java:922)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil.write(FileUtil.java:425)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.getContent(AggregateFilter.java:408)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.aggregate.AggregateFilter.processFilter(AggregateFilter.java:508)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1748.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.language.LanguageFilter.processFilter(LanguageFilter.java:84)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1748.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1748.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.cache.CacheFilter.processFilter(CacheFilter.java:421)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1748.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1748.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169)
 com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.header.HeaderFilter.processFilter(HeaderFilter.java:154)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor270.invoke(Unknown Source)
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67)
 com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1748.doFilter(Unknown Source)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:116)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:165)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortalClassLoaderFilter.doFilter(PortalClassLoaderFilter.java:74)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:204)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109)
 com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:96)

JBWEB000072: note JBWEB000073: The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1 logs.
```

Enviorment:

liferay 6.2

App server: jboss

I am trying to display the custom error message whenever the 500 exception i.e internal server error occurs.
Below are setting available in web.xml

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/code.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/code.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

Also i changed the code.jsp and added the custom code. Just simple text error message. But it is not calling the code.jsp instead complete stack trace is getting printed on browser.
The url i am hitting is:

```
https://localhost/xyzportlet/js/xyz.js?browserId=firefox&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6210&t=1424361709000&fakeParam=%24{76428%2b66104%2b%27f60cec015d33e6f70fc90789dd6659ff6b83da4d49f58d1fb7d1f0ae210ff7a8de500d534018c03aa77a440178e47b9e9dc66b53afa119163810502c2d1946f2%27}
```

And the error message i am getting is:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 500 - /jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host/xyz-portlet/aggregate/https_/xyz-portlet/js/xyz.jsbrowserId=firefox&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6210&t=1424361709000&fakeParam=%24{76428%2b66104%2b%27f60cec015d33e6f70fc90789dd6659ff6b83da4d49f58d1fb7d1f0ae210ff7a8de500d534018c03aa77a440178e47b9e9dc66b53afa119163810502c2d1946f2%27}_E_CONTENT_TYPE (File name too long)
```

Also instead of calling js if i call other jsp,css or other , it gives resource not found error instead of 500.

Anyone let me know what i am missing to handle 500 exceptions

Comment: Is this on a Windows machine? If so, your path is probably too long (Windows can only handle 260 characters) and you could try to shorten it (maybe move the working directory to a root folder).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jboss/jboss-eap-6.1/standalone/tmp/work/jboss.web/default-host/empAppMgmt-portlet/aggregate/https_/empAppMgmt-portlet/js/empAppMgmt.jsbrowserId=firefox&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6210&t=1424361709000&fakeParam=%24{76428%2b66104%2b%27f60cec015d33e6f70fc90789dd6659ff6b83da4d49f58d1fb7d1f0ae210ff7a8de500d534018c03aa77a440178e47b9e9dc66b53afa119163810502c2d1946f2%27}_E_CONTENT_TYPE (File name too long)
```

It looks as if the file name is too long. I would try correcting that first and then seeing if you still have the issue.

You might also try this:

> 1) SessionErrors.add(portletRequest , error.key)
>
> 2) Go to your Jsp
>   where you want to display this message and use this tag
>
> (with the "<" symbol in front of it of course, without the quotations)
>
> liferay-ui:error key="error.key"
>   message="error.message">
>
> 3) and write complete message inside language.properties for this key 
>   error.message = Custom Message

and check out [This Source](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/1502127).

I hope this helps!!

Comment: It would not let that tag line appear as part of a code block with the proper symbols in it, here is what that tag of step 2 should look like:

<liferay-ui:error key="error.key" message="error.message">